# software center in fedora 20 not working?

Tags: fedora, software-installation, gnome, cinnamon

I install gnome software centre by :  `sudo yum install gnome-software`

but when i open software centre it shows nothing [image]

**NOTE : I am Using Fedora 20 Cinnamon DE**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running F20 as well and your version looks a bit different than mine.

[image: ss1]

I would suggest un-installing it and trying to re-install. If that doesn't work then it's likely that the application maintains configuration info, perhaps in the `$HOME/.config` directory. I'd attempt to remove any files/directories related to this app and try running it with a clean slate.

#### Tracking down apps caches

You can use this trick to find out what directories `gnome-software` is accessing using `strace`.

```
$ strace -s 2000 -o gnome-software.log gnome-software
```

You can then `grep` through the resulting log file, `gnome-software.log` to see what locations the app's accessing. Typically with GNOME apps, there are config files under `$HOME/.config`.

Comment: @Slim   Thanks ..worked for me...but Why there is no minimize and Progress bar in it ???

Comment: @AshutoshKale - that seems to be the direction that GNOME 3.x is moving. I find it extremely annoying too. I'm also using Cinnamon 8-)

Comment: `yum install gnome-tweak-tool` (or find it in Software Center) will allow you to enable the minimize button (and lots of other tweaks too).

Comment: @garethTheRed - thanks I use that too. Forgot to mention it, I generally setup my laptop/destkop the way I want and then sit on it for long periods of time until either the hardware dies or I have to upgrade to a newer version of Fedora 8-). I used that tool + a whole host of plugins to Cinnamon back in June/July and have now forgotten about them.

Comment: I had the same problem, the config file is at `~/.local/share/gnome-software`. However the problem was with my repo data: `repodata ***** was not complete: Unknown checksum type "md5" for /var/cache/PackageKit/metadata/****/repodata/filelists.xml.gz`. So check your yum! funny strace did not show anything about accessing filelists.xml.gz. Running `sudo gnome-software` did it for me. it prints the ugly `org.gnome.Software:3891): Gs-WARN1` messages directly to terminal. Hope this helps someone.